# Installing Zend Server along with Apache server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, zend-server

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 operating system. I have already Apache, PHP, Mysql configured and running without any issues on my system. Now I would like to install Zend Server in my system will this break my already present Apache sever? Will there be any issues?

Comment: You will have to use different ports. Both will not be able to respond to the default 80 at the same time (or any port for that matter).

Comment: At present my apache server works with http://localhost. If i install zend server will localhost stop working or zend server has to be opened with another port like 8080 and localhost will work fine?